# How to get user Access Token without log in using facebook graph API 2.11

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the access_token of user profile using facebook graph API 2.11 the condition is user will not log in I have read many docs but nothing is working for me I have also tried to do this using app access token like this

> $accessToken = app_id|app_secret;

But by doing so it returns this exception.

> Graph returned an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I want to do this is PHP.

I hope i have explained my issue well if not please pardon me as I am not expert in asking questions

Comment: **Access Token without log in** as i know access token will generate once you logged in only

Comment: i think you should read this article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: Yes you are right but I think we can also get it from sessions all we need is the correct way to do so and I am searching for that correct way

Comment: @BilalAhmed I have already used this and it is working fine for me now I need to show the comments of that photo which has been uploaded to facebook but to do that i need access token again and I don't want user to login again to see comments

Comment: You can only get the access token when the user logs in.

Comment: I have done a work around and achieved what I wanted I have used some Jquery to trigger login event as soon as user lands on that page by this way user won't login himself but I'll get my access token don't know if it is correct way or not but it is working for me

Comment: extended user tokens are valid for 60 days. read about the tokens in the official docs.

Comment: Yes, I have read it but I now have the LongLived Access token which has more validity than the extended tokens anyways validity was never my concern as when ever user lands on that page my script will automatically generates a new access token so the validation time starts from the start again this way my token will never gets expire.